# When I toggle Tabs,Slides autoplay is not work.How to fix it?

Tags: angular, typescript, ionic2

This is my html:

```
<ion-slides (ionSlideDidChange)="slideChanged($index)">
    <ion-slide *ngFor="let slide of slidesInf 
      (click)="toSlideDetail(slide)">
        <img style="height:200px;width: 100% " [attr.src]="slide.src"/>
        <div [style.background]='slide.styleBackgroundColor' 
         class="slidesShade">{{slide.title}}</div>
    </ion-slide>
</ion-slides>
```

This my ts:

```
import {Component} from '@angular/core'
import {NavController} from 'ionic-angular';
import {ViewChild} from '@angular/core';
import {Slides} from 'ionic-angular';
import {ArticalDetail} from "../articalDetail/articalDetail";

@Component({
  selector: 'page-category',
  templateUrl: 'category.html'
})
export class Category {
@ViewChild(Slides) slides: Slides;
constructor(public navCtrl: NavController) {
}

public items: {} = [];
public slidesInfo: {} = [];

ngAfterViewInit() {
 this.slides.autoplay = 2500;
 this.slides.loop = true;
 this.slides.speed = 350;
 this.slides.autoplayDisableOnInteraction=false;
 this.initItems();
 this.initSlides();
}

toSlideDetail(item){
  this.navCtrl.push(ArticalDetail, {id: item.id});
}
```

When I click anther foot tabs,then go back to this page.my slides is not work.
I have tried to do something like this:

```
ionViewDidEnter() {
  this.slides.autoplay = 2500;
}
```

But it didn't work.
What should I do?

Comment: Try move your code from `ngAfterViewInit` to `ionViewDidEnter`.

Comment: try it,inconformity expectations.